# Can my FIFO queue utilizing 2 stacks be optimized or improved upon?

Tags: swift, optimization, fifo

I am creating a **FIFO queue using 2 stacks (arrays)** but I want to know if this is the best way using a class or is there further optimization that can be done here? I'm not sure if creating an extension where the `element == [Int]` would be considered better or not in this case.

```
//FIFO queue with 2 (arrays) Stacks
class MyQue {
    var que: [[Int]]
    init() {
        self.que = [[Int]]()
    }
    func pop() -> Int? {
        if !que.isEmpty {
            var flatArray = que.flatMap({$0})
            let removalIndex = que.firstIndex(of: que.first ?? [0])
            que.remove(at: removalIndex ?? 0)
            return flatArray.removeFirst()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        
    }
    func popCollection() -> [Int]? {
        if !que.isEmpty {
            return que.remove(at: 0)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        
    }
    func peek() -> Int? {
        if que.isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            return que.flatMap({$0}).first
        }
    }
    func push(_ x: [Int]) {
        var appendingArray = [Int]()
        for value in x {
            appendingArray.append(value)
        }
        que.append(appendingArray)
    }
    func empty() -> Bool {
        return que.isEmpty
    }
    func numberOfElements() -> Int {
        return que.count
    }
    func hasValue(value x: Int) -> Bool? {
        for val in que {
            return val.contains(x)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling and printing results

```
let myQue = MyQue()
let searchedValue = 10
myQue.push([4,6,4])
myQue.push([5, 99])
myQue.push([9, 12, 10])
print("myQue after init: \(myQue.que)")
let poppedValue = myQue.popCollection()
let popStringValue = poppedValue != nil ? poppedValue!.map{(String($0))}.joined(separator: ",") : "nil"
let peekStringValue = myQue.peek() != nil ? String(myQue.peek()!) : "nil"
let hasValueStringValue = myQue.hasValue(value: searchedValue) != nil ?
                            String(myQue.hasValue(value: searchedValue)!) : "nil"

print("myQue.pop(): \(popStringValue)")
print("myQue.peek(): \(peekStringValue)")
print("myQue.empty(): \(myQue.empty())")
print("myQue.hasValue(\(searchedValue)): \(hasValueStringValue)")
print("myQue.numberOfElements: \(myQue.numberOfElements())")
print("myQue: \(myQue.que)")
```

Comment: Code review questions are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Looking for more of an optimal solution and thoughts rather than a strict code review but thank you for the information

Comment: Maybe a more useful exercise could be to make the class generic.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that is a great suggestion and i will try it! thank you!